# AirPlay to a computer from a mobile device

Tags: streaming, ios, airplay

Is there an application that will allow me to stream music from my iOS device (iPod, iPad, iPhone, etc...) to a computer?

My particular setup involves an iPhone 4 and a MacBook Pro. I'm in full control of all devices and can setup AppleID's or anything else that needs to be in place.

Answer (score 0):

According to [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5802958/how-to-make-your-entire-home-airplay+compatible), Try [AirMac](http://code.google.com/p/airmac/feeds).